# Java API for fiddler files

Tags: java, fiddler

Fiddler produces a zip file (.saz is actually zip) with a list of request (3 files for each request).

Is there a Java API for reading fiddler files (with a nice data oo model). The hard way is possible, we know :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Java attempt to support the SAZ format (which can use up to 4 files per HTTP session). The Charles Proxy debugger (written in Java) was supposed to support the SAZ format, but it was broken last time I checked.

Stepping back a little bit-- what are you hoping to accomplish? Why not have Fiddler export the data into whatever format you'd like? For instance, Fiddler can export into HAR format, and I suspect there's a Java-based reader for HAR files...